# Set default subject when click on email address

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I am using dataDetectorTypes property with UITextView.code works fine.

When I click on link email composer appears with pre-filled To:[email address] but i want to set default Subject:[subject string] also.

How can I do this?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

1)Fist add  `<UITextViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>` to the class that contains the textview.

You must add two imports to this class:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
```

2) Add a variable: `MFMailComposeViewController` (in this example mailVC, you can also add it as a class property in your .h)

3) Implement the next method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
```

This allows to intercepts the specific url interaction. You can cancel a specific interaction and add your own action, for example:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange{
   //EXAMPLE CODE
    if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"mailto"]) {

        mailVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [mailVC setToRecipients:@[@"your@destinationMail.com"]];
        [mailVC setSubject:@"A subject"];
        mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [self presentViewController:mailVC animated:YES completion:^{
           // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
        }];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

3) To dismiss your MFMailComposeViewController variable:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
    [mailVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

That works for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController =    [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; 

   mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
    [mailController setSubject:@"Subject"];
    [mailController setMessageBody:@"Email body here" isHTML:NO]; 
    [mailController setMessageBody:[self getInFo] isHTML:YES]; 
    [mailController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"xx@xxx.com"]];
    [mailController setTitle:@"Title"];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES]; 
}else{
    [mailController release];
}
```

Comment: This is not what i am looking for. I want to add subject when I try to send mail by clicking on email in uitextview and dataDetectorTypes property is set to UIDataDetectorTypeAll.